# Make meta-electron compatible with jethro Yocto version

Tags: clang, electron, yocto, openembedded

I'm trying to cross-compile Electron on the [DIGI's ConnectCore6](http://www.digi.com/products/embedded-systems/single-board-computers/connectcore-6-sbc). To do so, I'm using Yocto and the [5 layers](http://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001945-13/default.htm#reference/yocto/r_system_development_yocto.htm%3FTocPath%3DDigi%2520Embedded%2520Yocto%7CSystem%2520development%7C_____0) provided by DIGI (all based on the **jethro** version of Yocto).

Or, to implement Electron on the SBC, I have to use the [meta-electron layer](https://github.com/OSSystems/meta-electron), which has four dependencies :

- `openembedded-core`
- `meta-openembedded`
- `meta-clang` (see [this](https://github.com/kraj/meta-clang))
- `meta-browser` (see [this](https://github.com/OSSystems/meta-browser/))

Unfortunately, these dependencies have to be considered in their respective **master** version, not the **jethro** ones. Also, DIGI provides the `poky` layer instead of the `openembedded-core` layer.

So, to try to use Electron on the ConnectCore6, I downloaded `meta-clang` (**master version**), `meta-browser` (**jethro version**), `meta-electron` (**master version**) and I added these layers to my `bblayers.conf`.

But, because of the jethro version of my poky layer, I have the following error for meta-clang, which can't find `musl` in the poky layer.

> ERROR: No recipes available for:
>   /usr/local/dey-2.0/sources/meta-clang/recipes-core/musl/musl_%.bbappend

`musl` is available in the **master branch of poky**, but not in the jethro branch. Of course, I tried to copy-paste the `musl` directory from master to jethro branch of poky but this just bring more errors and more missing recipes (`bsd-headers-devs`, `musl-dev`, ...).

Do you know how to fix this last error and/or how to make musl compatible with the jethro version of poky ? I really need help on this point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding [meta-musl](https://github.com/kraj/meta-musl) layer into the mix (with [jethro branch](https://github.com/kraj/meta-musl/tree/jethro)), it adds musl support for oe-core jethro. These days almost all of it is merged into main oe-core repository, but for your particular case it might help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I added this layer (jethro branch) but now I get the following messages : `WARNING: No recipes available for: gcc-source_linaro-4.9.bbappend, gcc-cross-initial_linaro-4.9.bbappend, gcc-crosssdk_linaro-4.9.bbappend, libgcc-initial_linaro-4.9.bbappend, gcc_linaro-4.9.bbappend, libgfortran_linaro-4.9.bbappend, gcc-runtime_linaro-4.9.bbappend, gcc-sanitizers_linaro-4.9.bbappend, libgcc_linaro-4.9.bbappend, gcc-cross-canadian_linaro-4.9.bbappend, gcc-crosssdk-initial_linaro-4.9.bbappend, gcc-cross_linaro-4.9.bbappend`. Do you have an idea how to fix this ? Thanks again.

Comment: @AntoineD: wow, no fun. That's where I'd probably think about making a local fork of some repo to clean it up. Maybe meta-musl, since there are no updates expected for it and you can just fork it, remove bbappends for linaro toolchains and that would be it.